# react copy to clipboard usage doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I copy `content` when it's clicked once? below is my code, but when I clicked and do ctrl + v, it's not been copied

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "",
    copied: false
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CopyToClipboard
          text={this.state.value}
          onCopy={text => this.setState({ copied: true, text })}
        >
          <span>content</span>
        </CopyToClipboard>
        {this.state.copied ? (
          <span style={{ color: "red" }}>Copied.</span>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard

Comment: what text you are copying, what is source of `this.state.value`?, check the [working doc example](https://codepen.io/nkbt/pen/eNPoQv?editors=0010)

Comment: @MayankShukla `content`

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing `this.state.value` in your program. Try setting it in your code with which value you are trying to copy.